# How do I Filter a Pandas DataFrame After using read_csv() or read_excel()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Just started learning about pandas so this is most likely a simple question.

Is there a way to filter a csv or xls file based on the value of a column while you are reading it in or by chaining another function or selector? For example I want to do something like this all in one line.

file:

```
Name,Age    
Mike,25   
Joe,19
Mary,30
```

When I read in the file I want to filter on Age

```
pd.read_csv('file.csv')['Age' >= 21]
#or
pd.read_excel('file.xls')['Age' >= 21]
```

Comment: You need to just read the [pandas documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/), which explains in detail how to do this and tons of other things.  There is for instance a section called "indexing and selecting data".

Comment: Can you clarify the question: Your title says "after" but text says "while ... reading".  After means the entire data is in memory, then a filtered copy is constructed.  Memory consumption will be sum of both for a period of time. *While* implies that line by line, the CSV source is filtered.  Only the filtered data set is in memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
pd.read_csv('file.csv').query('Age >= 21')
```